# Feature extraction from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

hi i am new in matlab.... i want to detect sick cells in a image.

first i segmented the image by this code: 
  now i want to extract its features.... what should i do?
    please guide me?
    thanks

```
he = imread('hestain.png');
imshow(he), title('H&E image');
text(size(he,2),size(he,1)+15,...
     'Image courtesy of Alan Partin, Johns Hopkins University', ...
     'FontSize',7,'HorizontalAlignment','right');

cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_he = applycform(he,cform);
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
nColors = 3;
% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                      'Replicates',3);
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
for k = 1:nColors
    color = he;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end
imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');

imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');

imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');
```

Here is the image:
 [image]

Now i want to extract its features.... what should i do?
  please guide me?
  thanks

Comment: Search Google for "matlab for beginners"

Comment: Additionally read this blog, http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/

Comment: Which features do you want to extract?

Comment: I want to extract the feature of cancer cells.some cells in this picture are the cancer cells. the color of cancer cells have a special color range .in above picture some cells are became cancer cells and some are not. i want to distinguish cancer cells. what exactly i want to do is that , "is a pathology picture like the upon is a cancer one or not". 
please help me..
thank you so much.

Comment: @saeedtalaee: That sounds more like histology question than a signal processing one.

Comment: my question is that how to detect special saturation of that segmentation  in matlab.. that is it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**regionprops** function in matlab will extract different properties of detected blobs, here is a link [regionsprops](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html)

Comment: when i use your soultion , matlab give me this error:
??? Error using ==> iptcheckinput
Function BWLABEL expected its first
input, BW, to be two-dimensional.
please help me...

Error in ==> bwlabel at 67
iptcheckinput(BW, {'logical' 'numeric'},
{'real', '2d', 'nonsparse'}, ...

Answer (score 0):

Find the properties of each of your clusters aka cells by finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. These will indicate the "tubeness" of your cells. You can compute moments of each cell as well.

I have no idea what your "sick" cells look like, so coming up with a method to differentiate between healthy and sick cells is not possible if no one knows what a "sick" cell looks like. Post another image of what a sick cell looks like.

You can learn properties of tubeness and moments for each cell, and store them. Then use a Support Vector Machine to classify healthy vs sick cell. Use SVM-Light. http://svmlight.joachims.org/

Ankur

Comment: thank you for your great answer. but the the picture of upon is a cancer one. the color limitation in cancer cells are different from other cells. Cancer cells have more color saturation. I Should distinguish them from their saturation. now what should i do?
what are the steps after segmentation ?
thanks again

Comment: If you can differentiate healthy vs sick cells using saturation, then convert your image from RGB to HSV space. Now you should be able to see that the cancerous cells have high saturation, and a simple thresholding should work in detecting cancer cells